# Need help and a concise explanation for updating an existing constructor in C#

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I need to update my existing constructor to accept a value for the 'DateOfBirth' property...
I would really appreciate any help in solving the problem for me...
And a concise explanation for the solution would be very beneficial to me...
Thanks in advance!
Here is the code...

```
using System;

public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add another parameter to your constrctor of type DateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the constructor by adding one extra parameter `dateOfBirth`. Use this parameter to initialize your property `DateOfBirth`. This way, the `Person` can never be instantiated without a valid value for `DateOfBirth`.

```
public Person(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

now you can construct it like this:

```
Person p = new Person("John", "Smith", new DateTime(2010, 01, 13));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was of great help! I have realized my faults and have now rectified them!

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember, if this was the correct answer for you, to check the green tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor part is the 4th line - public Person.... - and you can tell it's the constructor because it has the same name as the class and no return type. To add in a new value you would need to change the constructor to:

```
public Person(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
    DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

I've stuck with the naming conventions of the existing string inputs and made an assumption that you want the constructor to use the input to set the property of the same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!